# How can I duplicate a record in MS ACCESS with ASP/VBscript and primary key?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, duplicates, primary-key, record

I'm searching for a simple method to duplicate a record (many many columns) in a MSAccess database. I'm working with ASP classic/VBscript pages and ADODB to execute SQL queries.
The record I want to duplicate has a primary key, so I cannot use the standard query

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=... ---> error
```

I only found this workaround (a temporary table), but I think it's not the best option:

```
<%
set RS=Conn.Execute("SELECT * INTO temptable FROM mytable WHERE id="&id
set RS=Conn.Execute("ALTER TABLE temptable ALTER COLUMN id INTEGER")
set RS=Conn.Execute("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM mytable")
maxid=RS("maxid")+1
set RS=Conn.Execute("UPDATE temptable SET id="&maxid)
set RS=Conn.Execute("INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM temptable")
set RS=Conn.Execute("DROP TABLE temptable")
%>
```

I could also specify all column names in my query, but I have a huge number of columns, and they're often modified (I don't want to keep track of all db structure changes)

Any better solution? Thanks

Comment: Do not `SELECT *`, select all relevant fields by name. That is, all fields except Id.

Comment: @Remou is 100% correct, and just in support of his comment; this is the problem you are encountering. When you `SELECT * FROM Table` you are selecting everything, including the `IDENTITY` fields that make each row unique/different. This must be avoided. You must select each column you want to duplicate, and avoid the `ID` column. For example: `SELECT FirstName, LastName, MiddleInitial, BirthDate FROM USERS`

Comment: RecordSets have a fields collections. So do something lile `For each col in rs.Fields:if col.name <> PrimID then StarString= StarString & col.name & " ":next`. There is more to a recordset than sql.

Answer (score 0):

The probelm with duplicating the record is that primary keys are unique. If the record must exist in the same table, it has to have a different primary key. I suggest adding another column(s) to the table where you can put the origianl primary key. You can make a reasonalbe query that duplicates the record, saves the original primary key and assigns a new unique key to this record.

Frequently, the primary key is meaningless, i.e., assigned by the database (autonumber). You can use the technique pointed out by OverMind to access all of the columns (fields).

I used Scripting Dictionaries and routines that copied fields from RecordSets to the Scripting Dictionaries, from Scripting Dictionaries to other scripting Dictionaries and from Scripting Dictionaries to RecordSets to avoid the stright line code for copying records from one table to another where the number of fields was large.

I will share the service routines, if you want, but the code that actually moves the data around is proprietry.